# Extended resonance and colour

Tags: organic-chemistry, color

I was pretty sure that this would've been asked before but I couldn't find anything here. I've noticed that system with multiple benzene rings and pi donating/accepting groups tend to be quite colourful compared to their less conjugated counterparts, like azo dyes or indophenol or methylene blue. My guess is that the extended conjugation somehow pushes down the energy gap between the ground state and excited state, which  kicks up the wavelength of light absorption out of the UV spectrum perhaps by molecular orbital magic.

1. Is there any rigorous explanation for this observation?
   (Answered)
2. Naphthalene and anthracene are both colourless, so do the nitrogen/oxygen substituents play an important role in imparting colour ie why do heteroatoms seem to create more colourful molecules?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84720/explaining-color-differences-using-bond-conjugation

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109670/finding-the-color-of-crystal-violet-theoretically https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/10648/9961

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67770/simple-way-to-understand-why-chromophores-often-have-double-bonds

Comment: In your defence, starting search with resonance and colour proved to be a surprisingly bad approach, while it shouldn't be. Your question might fix it.

Comment: This answer by Philipp is delightful, thank you very much.

Comment: There's more in follow-up https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/the-energy-gap-between-a-pi-conjugated-system-with-2-bonding-and-1-anti-bonding

Comment: Umm, you closed it yourself, and then started reopening :/ Some of the links^ talk about substituents.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't know that answering yes would close the question.

Comment: @Mithoron do i delete this question then? i don't know the procedure here

Comment: No, it may be useful to have a duplicate like this one, like I mentioned earlier. I didn't put all these links just for you.